# How to make softinput cover the screen bottom?

Tags: android, window-soft-input-mode

Now one of my layout with edittext align in the bottom ,when the edittext is clicked,the whole page moved up and make room for the softinput;
But I just want the bottom layout moved up,the solution is ?

Comment: @Abhi what I want is like this:At first, the edittext align in the bottom.when the edittext is inputting, the edittext moves up to make room for the softinput window, but the page doesn't moved up

Comment: THere is no mode for that.  Your only options are-  resize the app, pan the app (the entire app is scrolled if needed to assure the edit text is on screen), or do nothing.

Comment: @Abhi I never want to try the resize mode because I mistake  it would compress the whole page....Ok, i'm wrong, I should have try that.LOL

Comment: Right. There is no compression.

Comment: @Abhi by the way do know how to dismiss the animation when the softinput is opening or closing? I mean,I want it open or close immediately when I call it rather than taking time to start animation to it

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a stack of Ten plates. You Put another plate at the botton, number eleven plate, I mean. Do you really think only th eplate number ten willmove, and not the others? Seriously?

Comment: hah,seriously, on my page there only exsits one edittext so...no worry guy

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to make a change to your manifest file: I use this one to let the soft keyboard appear and making the rest of the view scrollable:

```html
<activity 
            android:name=".GroupProperties"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"
            android:label="@string/groepsleden_toevoegen"
            >
        </activity>
```

Depending on your layout you might also use

android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">